# @BOOKMARK error with .bib file of achemso-demo template

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I am trying to compile a template provided in JACS website by Joseph Wright. Although it is compiled w/o any error (if I exclude the package `mhchem`), when I add my `.bib` file, I have an error message saying that `! Paragraph ended before \@BOOKMARK was complete`. Would you have any suggestion about my problem?  Here is the document from the template: `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title {\bf Synergistic effect in the co-assembly of type-I and type-III
  collagens}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
co-fibril of type-I/III\\
 \cite{silver84}: monomer lengths Table 1 - fix author names\\
\cite{romanic91}: type-III co-assembles with type-I and makes fibrils 
   thinner.\\
\bigskip

\bibliography{achemso-demo}
\end{document}
```

My bib file is: `test.bib`

```
@article{silver84,
  title={Molecular structure of collagen in solution: comparison of types {I}, {II}, {III} and {V}},
  author={Silver, F H and Birk, D E},
  journal={Int. J. Biol. Macromol.},
  volume={6},
  number={3},
  pages={125--132},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{romanic91,
  title={Copolymerization of p{N}collagen {III} and collagen {I}. p{N}collagen {III} decreases the rate of incorporation of collagen {I} into fibrils, the amount of collagen {I} incorporated, and the diameter of the fibrils formed.},
  author={Romanic, A M and Adachi, E and Kadler, K E and Hojima, Y and Prockop, D J},
  journal={J. Biol. Chem.},
  volume={266},
  number={19},
  pages={12703--12709},
  year={1991},
  publisher={ASBMB}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: never use `\bf` in a LaTeX document - it was obsolete 20 years ago. But you shouldn't have manual markup in the argument to something like `\title` anyway...

Answer (score 2):

I get no error if I load `hyperref` instead of `hypdoc` (that's an addition relative to the `doc` package, which is out of place here). Also you shouldn't use `geometry` and `setspace`, as the class already takes care of the pagination settings. Loading `lmodern` is useless if you later load `mathpazo`. You don't need `xkeyval`, which is a helper package for other packages, nor `natbib` that's already loaded by the class.

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last, with the choice of packages you have.

Avoid explicit markup such as `\bf` (which, by the way, is an obsolete command) in `\title`: the class already does the desired thing.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{silver84,
  title={Molecular structure of collagen in solution: comparison of types {I}, {II}, {III} and {V}},
  author={Silver, F H and Birk, D E},
  journal={Int. J. Biol. Macromol.},
  volume={6},
  number={3},
  pages={125--132},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{romanic91,
  title={Copolymerization of p{N}collagen {III} and collagen {I}. p{N}collagen {III} decreases the rate of incorporation of collagen {I} into fibrils, the amount of collagen {I} incorporated, and the diameter of the fibrils formed.},
  author={Romanic, A M and Adachi, E and Kadler, K E and Hojima, Y and Prockop, D J},
  journal={J. Biol. Chem.},
  volume={266},
  number={19},
  pages={12703--12709},
  year={1991},
  publisher={ASBMB}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title {Synergistic effect in the co-assembly of type-I and type-III
  collagens}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
co-fibril of type-I/III

\cite{silver84}: monomer lengths Table 1 - fix author names

\cite{romanic91}: type-III co-assembles with type-I and makes fibrils 
   thinner.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

In the example I use `filecontents` just for making it self-contained; use your bib file name instead of `\jobname` in the argument to `\bibliography`.

[image]

Comment: @cfr Right. Removed.

Comment: Can't upvote twice... ;).

Comment: @egreg, Thanks very much for your informative answer. 'chemgreek' file is still causing error, but since I do not really need that, my document is compiled w/o any error now!.